# Drop down list with large number of words in each selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an unusual situation. I have a drop down list that allows my users to select one of a number of different scenarios. My problem is that each scenario is about 100 words long. I want to show the user everything and a radio selection box would not be appropriate. What happens is that because of the very long rows my dropdown list appears so wide that it goes off the edge of the page.

Is there a way that I can split up text (I'm using C#) and add new lines so that dropdown list box contains "multi line" selections?

Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Have you considered short descriptions in the options, and adding `title="This is the full description that will be in the browser popup"` to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without some scripting. You can add `width` and `white-space:pre-wrap` to your `select` tag, but that only wraps the visible part. You can't, as Madmargigan suggested, use a title to show the complete string (the title won't show).

I have prepared a very basic script to demonstrate how you could do this with javascript. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veXrr/). It may give you ideas?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Your suggestion is great. Marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi Marika, glad I could help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with the standard html dropdownlist.  Some frameworks have workarounds for it (for instance, see [ASP.NET's dropdownlist](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/DropDown/DropDown.aspx)).  There are also javascript libraries that offer solutions to this problem as well.